# What does the work "Kitaku" mean?

Tags: translation, nuances, colloquial-language, word-usage

I understand this to mean "return home". I am thinking about starting a new company and I would like something to mean, "return back to my roots, back to a safe place". Would "kitaku" be a word that could have this meaning?

Comment: Hi welcome to the site! Does this [Difference between 帰宅する and 帰る](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/66561/difference-between-%e5%b8%b0%e5%ae%85%e3%81%8d%e3%81%9f%e3%81%8f%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b-and-%e5%b8%b0%e3%81%8b%e3%81%88%e3%82%8b) answer to your question?

Answer (score 1):

"Kitaku(帰宅)" literally means "to go home".
It may make viewers imagine that workers go home or that come to our office as your home.

If you want to know a cool Japanese phrase that means something like "return back to my roots, back to a safe place", I come up with the phrase "Gentenkaiki(原点回帰)".